# Express routing hello world in the browser from their example docs does nothing

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I want to serve html to the browser but for now just 'Hello World'

When I navigate to https://example.com/test

## EDIT: my site is not example.com I just can't type the name

the console does not log a request

404 in the browser if I don't create the directory, 403 forbidden if I do create it.

node.js code:

```
var express=require(__dirname+'/../node_modules/express');
var app = express()

app.get('/test', function(req,res){
  console.log(req);
  res.send('Hello World')
})

app.listen(10001);
```

I get no node.js errors

the port 10001 is open!

I can't find any docs beyond http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html which just assumes that what they tell you to do will just work so they go into ZERO detail!

I totally 100% do not understand this!

Comment: You're actually trying to open `https://example.com/test` in your browser and expecting it to point to your local running Node server?

Comment: I want to serve dynamic files with out the users needing to type a port

Comment: It would be helpful if you actually answered the questions being asked...

Comment: Local? the Node server is on my website

Comment: No my host name is private for now ahhhh

Comment: You will have to explain where and how you're hosting that website online otherwise it will be impossible to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: .........................correct!

Comment: centos7 on hosting studio.net

Comment: Hmm... and what are you using to proxy the requests to the node service?

Comment: Please update your question with hosting details and if you are getting error, check the log generated after hosting. That will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Where are you hosting? If local, are you including the port in your URL?
If you are using a local dev server, it should be something like

```
https://localhost:10001/test
```

Comment: I don't want users to type the ugly port in the address bar that's what i thought the route is for!

Comment: The next layer depends on where you are hosting. If you are using something like Firebase Functions / Google Cloud Functions to host this express app, you will need to make sure requests are routed to this function. app.get('<path>' - only handles traffic that is received by the function. I would check to ensure that your platform level routing is correct. Then the express level routing kicks in.  This is a firebase example of routing an https request to an express app function: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions#direct_hosting_requests_to_your_function

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to serve your app on a server at port 10001. If your domain is example.com, you have to go to http://example.com:10001/test. When you try to connect to the website using a browser, the browser will automatically assume the port is 80 and it will try to connect to that port.

Also you can use `const express = require("express")`.